# jQuery opacity and fadeTo(); in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, opacity, fadeto

this bit dont work:

```
$(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.4, function() {
                    $(this).addClass('hidden')
                });
```

so i tested this:

```
$(this).css('opacity',0.3);
```

no success in IE8  :/ (IE7 + Chrom + FF + Safari everything ok - debbuging js everthing ok... )

so i went on google and searched the problem and tried this:

```
 $.fn.customFadeTo = function(speed,to,callback) {
    return this.animate({opacity: to}, speed, function() {
        if (to == 1 && jQuery.browser.msie)
            this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
        if (jQuery.isFunction(callback))
            callback();
    });
};
```

and this (CSS...):

```
display:inline-block;
```

still no no success in IE8... any help???

UPDATE:
this seams to work:

```
$(this).children('img').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {});
```

so its a problem with the images

UPDATE:
the DOM element -> $(this) refers to

```
<a class="alle-referenzen referenzenDetailLink" href="webdesign-referenzen-hotel-chesa-randolina" title="Hotel Chesa Randolina"> 
                <span> 
                    <b>Hotel Chesa Randolina</b><br /> 
                    Webdesign, Blog, CMS, Programmierung, Suchmaschinenoptimierung
                </span> 
                <img src="/images/content/Referenzen/HotelRandolina/Website_Hotel-Randolina.jpg" alt="Hotel Chesa Randolina" /> 
                <img class="out" src="/images/content/Referenzen/HotelRandolina/Logo_Hotel-Randolina.jpg" alt="Hotel Chesa Randolina" />            
            </a>
```

Comment: this means the bit of code after the :

Comment: meaning what dom element does `this` refer to? `<a>`, `<div>`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you says "this bit won't work" but have given no indication of what you want to achieve nor what the result of that code was or what `this` refers to.

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/YhzPh/ which I made in relation another question to see if that helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i know this post was a bit slopy...

this bit won't work -> this pice of code 
" no indication of what you want to achieve" -> $(this) (A specific div) should fade out

i will try it with your input... thanks for now